# How to access github tag message in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions, git-tag

I want to capture the github tag message in Github Actions.

If user pushes tag with some message e.g.

```
git tag -a 1.0.0 -m "Test Message"
```

than, I would like to capture that message("Test Message") inside the github actions.

Any help or reference is much appreciated.

Comment: fyi, you can answer your own question as a proper answer and then select it  as the answer for the question 

Comment: point noted. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not able to run git command through github actions. Validate the checkout log, you should have something like this

```
git version 2.17.1 
Deleting the contents of <YOUR REPO> 
The repository will be downloaded using the GitHub REST API 
To create a local Git repository instead, add Git 2.18 or higher to the PATH
Downloading the archive Writing archive to disk Extracting the archive
```

Install the latest version of git as per your requirement. I have used [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egit-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to install on ubuntu self hosted runner.
Once version issue is fixed and github action is cloning the repo instead of downloading through rest api. Than use below command

```
git fetch --depth=1 origin +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
git tag -l --format='%(contents:subject)' ${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}
```

Comment: Sweet! Worked like a charm. Thank. For anyone else interested here is what it looks like then applying the tag message to environment variable for use elsewhere in the Github Actions script: 
`echo "TAG_MESSAGE=$(git tag -l --format='%(contents:subject)'${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/})" >> $GITHUB_ENV`